# XeLaTeX: Arial small caps

Tags: overleaf, small-caps, arial

I'm searching for the way to use \textsc and \scshape when I compile with XeLaTeX my document and I set Arial font.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Arial}
```

I am using Overleaf.

Comment: never use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with xelatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided no example showing your problem, it should just work with no additional definitions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

Abc \textsc{Abc}

\end{document}
```

Note That this assumes a full modern Arial as distributed with Windows. The Arial available in linux (including Overleaf) is an older version with fewer variants. However you can use the TeX Gyre Helvetica clone.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
 \title{Example} \author{Francesco Contini}
\date{December 2021}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\section{Introduction} This is an \textsc{example}.
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}

Abc \textsc{Abc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still problems.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\title{Example}
\author{Francesco Contini}
\date{December 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is an \textsc{example}.

\end{document}

Comment: This is the link to my example document.
https://it.overleaf.com/1625286962hfdqtkyxryjn

Comment: @cicciocontini your example [makes this output, looks oK to me, texlive 2021](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsPfl.png)

Comment: @cicciocontini I added an explanation and Overleaf solution